# connect call on client side unix socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, ip

I am a newbie to Unix networking and I cannot understand what is wrong with my code. I have researched a lot and logically the code should work but I am pulling my hair out right now. The client side connect call keeps throwing an error - setting `errno` to `22`. I don't understand what is wrong with the way arguments to connect are being passed.

The client side code is:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char buffer[256];
    uint32_t
    serverip=; //ip goes here

    struct sockaddr_in clientsock;
    memset(&clientsock, 0, sizeof(clientsock));
    clientsock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientsock.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(serverip);
    clientsock.sin_port = htons((unsigned short) 5000);
    socklen_t clientsocksize = sizeof(clientsock);
    int clientfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    int retval = -1;

    retval = connect(clientfd, (struct sockaddr*) &clientsock,
            sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    while (1)
    {
        if (retval == -1)
        {
            printf("error while connecting...\n");
            printf("error: %i\n", errno);
            retval = connect(clientfd, (struct sockaddr*) &clientsock,
                    sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        }
        else if (retval == 0)
        {
            printf("connection returned: %i\n", retval);
            printf("please enter data: ");
            bzero((char *) &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
            write(clientfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error in else: %i\n", errno);

        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance and critique would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: at which point does he throw that error`?

Comment: You are using INET sockets, not [tag:unix-socket]s.

Answer (score 0):

Errno 22 is `EINVAL`, which means some of the arguments you passed to `connect` are not valid. One of the possible error is that you are setting the sockaddr with assigning to a `uint32_t`:

```
uint32_t serverip=; //ip goes here
clientsock.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(serverip);
```

What is exactly the serverip? How do you get it? Generally you should call `getaddrinfo` or `inet_pton` to convert hostname or dotted ip string to `sockaddr.sin_addr`. For example, if you use `getaddrinfo`, you can use the `sockaddr` directly returned by it:

```
connect(clientfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
```

or if you use `inet_pton`,

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, ipstr, &clientsock.sin_addr.s_addr);
```

Also, it's better to check `socket` return value for any errors:

```
int clientfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (clientfd < 0) {
      // error
      exit(1);
}
```

Comment: serverip is the server's ip address - I am just hard coding that for now to test if I can successfully connect to the server. I used uint32_t because that is the type the address is stored in struct in_addr according to: https://linux.die.net/man/7/ip. I changed it and tried using inet_pton but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: What is the hardcoded value? It might play a role since you are also calling `htonl` on that.

Comment: @AliSyed Please post the exact error you get and the location where you get the error?

Comment: Connect returns -1 and then this code executes: if (retval == -1)
        {
            printf("error: %i\n", errno);
            retval = connect(clientfd, (struct sockaddr*) &clientsock,
                    sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        }.

Comment: the lines "error while connecting..\n" and "error: 22" print to screen iteratively then due to the while loop

Comment: @AliSyed There isn't "error while connecting" code in your post, so maybe update with the new code.

Comment: Apologies. Just did it. The gist of it is that connect() keeps returning -1.

Comment: I researched and used the inet_pton method and it worked. Thank you!